# How to prevent layout moving?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one main layout in my quiz game and in it 3 more nested layout, one below another, vertical. In the top one I have a text view for the question, the middle one with four buttons vertically arranged. Now, when I have one line question everything is fine, but as soon as question goes to two line, my buttons move down one row. How to prevent this? I want everything below my question to be fixed, static, not to move.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="404dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
         >
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPitanje"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tvPitanje"
        android:textSize="22sp" /> 
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bOdgovor1"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="@string/bOdgovor1"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bOdgovor2"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="@string/bOdgovor2"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bOdgovor3"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="@string/bOdgovor3"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bOdgovor4"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="@string/bOdgovor4"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIzlazIzKviza"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons"
            android:text="@string/bIzlazKviz"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCountdown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tvCountdown"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="29sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSkor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tvSkor"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBrojPitanja"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide xml layout

Comment: Here you go mate. The whole xml.

Answer (score 0):

A little later, but here we go, there are several solutions for this problem I will point out here two of them that probably are the most user friendly:

1. Use a scrollview for everything, IMHO this is the most user friendly solution.
2. Use scrollview just for text and buttons with a defined height, and put the below text and buttons static underneath, make use of a relative layout then.
3. Marquee text view

the first option I will put out here, with some layout refactoring included, the second one I wont recommend to use, put pretty simple to achieve if you have example one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/background_light"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvPitanje"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="long text that will automaticly scroll and make sure all content will be displayed right in the scrollview this is the best case scenario"
                        android:textSize="22sp"/>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bOdgovor1"
                        android:layout_width="260dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="one"
                        android:textSize="26sp"/>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bOdgovor2"
                        android:layout_width="260dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="two"
                        android:textSize="26sp"/>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bOdgovor3"
                        android:layout_width="260dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="three"
                        android:textSize="26sp"/>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bOdgovor4"
                        android:layout_width="260dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="four"
                        android:textSize="26sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/bIzlazIzKviza"
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                            android:text="left"
                            android:textSize="23sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvCountdown"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="next"
                            android:textColor="#ff0000"
                            android:textSize="29sp"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvSkor"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="middle"
                            android:textSize="23sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvBrojPitanja"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:text="right"
                            android:textSize="32sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Marquee solution less nice

```
android:singleLine="true" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: I get error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: Sorry it seems I forgot to paste some code :), I edited above answer. Now it should work. FYI indeed Scrollview can only contain one direct view. And in previous version I posted it had multiply. It should work now.

Comment: I triple checked it, you sure you copy pasted the above new xml code? Also try todo a clean and rebuild the project to make sure.

Comment: This is normal behaviour that is why using a scrollview is good. But you can also try marquee elipzed so the question will always be one line but just marquees. See the updated question how to do this.